# ENV value is not visible on server restart with bash daemon script

Tags: bash, daemon

I have an embedded jetty app that I want to start run automatically in the background by using a **‘start-stop-daemon’** script.
When I start the script as follows everything goes well.., and the ENV (environment variable) is visible to the startup app:

vagrant@homestead:~$ `sudo /etc/init.d/myscript start`

I have this in my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
:
:
DAEMON_USER=vagrant
:
:
# Source to load the secret key
source ~/.profile
:
:
start-stop-daemon --start --background --pidfile $PIDFILE --make-pidfile --user $DAEMON_USER --chuid $DAEMON_USER --chdir $MARY_BASE --startas $DAEMON -- $DAEMON_OPTS
:
```

When the script is automatically uploaded (server restart), the app is automatically start but the key value (ENV) is not visible to the startup app.

How to get the ENV value visible to the app on server startup with a daemon bash script?

Comment: Which variable specifically is not available where exactly?

Comment: ABC=123 in ~/.profile

Comment: `ABC=123` or `export ABC=123`? It needs to be exported for any child processes to use it.

Comment: What do you expect `~` is evaluating to when your script is started by the init/startup framework/service?

Comment: @ chepner, yep, of course: ```export ABC=123```, I've tried ```source ~/.profile``` and ```. ~/.profile``` both without success.

Comment: @ Etan Reisner, If I understand your question, so ```~/.profile``` is located in ```{HOME}/.profile``` , this is where I put ```export ABC=123```. I expect the startup app (Jetty) to get this key/value (secret key) at server startup.

Comment: ~/.profile means the roots home dir, correct?

Comment: The tilde (~) symbol stands for your home directory. If you are user, then the tilde (~) stands for ```/home/profile```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SOLVED]

In `~/.profile` you can place environment variable assignments, since it gets executed automatically during the start-up.

A suitable file for **system-wide environment variable** settings that affect the system as a whole (rather than just a particular user) is `/etc/environment`.

Copy your key (`export ABC=123`) to the above file and *source* it in your bash script (`. /etc/environment`).

I hope it can help someone.